# Set Permanent Environmental Variable in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, script, batch, command-line, environment-variables

I want to set environmental variables permanently through a batch file. Is there a command to set Permanent Environmental Variable (other than SETX) for Windows XP service pack 3?

command
SETX JAVA_HOME="C:\java\jdk-1.4"
is not supported in my machine. It is Windows XP service pack 3.

Comment: you mean specifically via command-line? or will a control panel suffice?

Comment: I want to do it through the batch file since it should be done for several machines.

Comment: You can also use `SETX`. See [this superuser post](http://superuser.com/a/505922/115481).

Comment: He said specifically that setx is not an option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per user settings command line:

```
% reg add KEY  /v JAVA_HOME /t REG_SZ /d "C:\java\jdk-1.4"
```

For user only settings replace KEY with:

```
HKCU\Environment
```

For per machine settings replace KEY with:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

(Attention: there is a space in the last key, quote it with `"` !)

Comment: hey can u tell me where can i find similar commands like this one.

Comment: define "similar". modifying the registry? thats not so similar to, lets say, deleting files. best way to find things is to have a problem and to search for an answer here on superuser and, if nothing fits, ask your next question

Comment: hey hey thank. Got what i wanted. Good work. Saved the day.Thanks again.

Comment: @shyameniw you told akira suggestion done fine, please say your complete command. thanks

Comment: @MJM: the command is the one i posted. right there, 2nd line.