# Set Permanent System variable through bat file

Tags: windows-xp, script, batch, command-line, environment-variables

*This is a follow-up to [Set Permanent Environmental Variable in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/135056/set-permanent-environmental-variable-in-windows-xp).*

I want to change System variables in XP through running a bat file. But when I run it I get the error ***"Too many command-line parameters"***

This is the code:

```
set KEY="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Sessions Manager\Environment"
set PATHxx=%Path%
reg add %KEY% /v Pathx /t REG_EXPAND_SZ 5 /d %PATHxx%
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the 5 be in there?

You've probably got spaces in your path

Try this:

```
set KEY="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Sessions Manager\Environment"
set PATHxx=%Path%
reg add %KEY% /v Pathx /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%PATHxx%"
```

You also might want to include:

> /f - Force overwriting the existing
>   registry entry without prompt

Comment: but still i get the error

Too many command-line parameters

Comment: I've updated my answer...

Comment: I've updated again!

Comment: hello, now it don't get the error, and it says

The operation completed successfully

But the environment variable Pathx is not created in Computer--> properties --> Advanced -->Environment Variables --> System Variables

Comment: @shyameniw - I think it's a permissions thing specific to that part of the registry. My testing did not allow me to create the key in that location but did elsewhere in the registry. Try a test to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\SuperUser` instead and check in Regedit to see if that created.