# Setting 'bookmarks' for command prompt on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, bookmarks

I know I can change the command prompt to startup on `C:\` rather than `F:\Documents And Settings` or wherever. But I was wondering if it's possible to set bookmarks or some other command that allows me to switch to locations.

For example, my Python projects have a long (about 7 subdirectories) address (think that's the word), and as such it takes a while to cd to them. What I would like to do is something like `gotodirectory PythonProjects` , and have it cd to where I have specified this, be it `C:\WINDOWS` or `F:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\some game\some game data\some more game data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the below in a batch file called "gotodirectory", place that file somewhere in you path.

Then use as follows -

> gotodirectory sys

The below batch also support changing to a different partitions.

Of course you can also add other commands.

---

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="sys" (
    cd /d C:\WINDOWS\System32
    goto :EOF
)
if "%1"=="home" (
    cd /d C:\Cygwin\home
    goto :EOF
)
if "%1"=="work" (
    cd /d C:\wwwroot
    goto :EOF
)
```

Comment: Since The Duck mentioned he is using Windows XP, using `cmd.exe` features would make the script much shorter. For one, you can force `cd` to change drive letters with `/d` option. (Using `pushd` would work nicely too.) Second, `goto :EOF` makes the explicit `:end` label unnecessary; there also is `exit /b`. Third, command grouping - either using `( )` or `&` - allows you to remove the rest of labels. (Feel free to revert the edit.)

Answer (score 1):

set an environment variable:

```
% set GD_PYTHONPROJECTS=C:\There\And\There
```

then use it like

```
% cd %GD_PYTHONPROJECTS%
```

how to set environmet variables permanently check out

[Set Permanent Environmental Variable in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/135056/set-permanent-environmental-variable-in-windows-xp)

(you can set environment variables permanently via the gui as well, they are stored in there registry anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file and keep it in a directory contained within the default path.

As an example - to get to *F:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\some game\some game data\some more game data*

```
f:
cd "F:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\some game\some game data\some more game data"
```

Save that as gotosteam.bat or any name you prefer and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the properties of `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` or create a shortcut to it and specify what directory you want it to start in (and even assign it a shortcut key).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx

"Cmd prompt here" context menu for windows explorer.