# Quotations Appearing at end of HOME variable value after setting to a Drive

Tags: environment-variables, windows-server-2012-r2

I recently changed the `HOME` variable to `C:\` on my server. Today, I noticed an issue where a bat script that makes some GIT calls wouldn't run because a concatenated path was invalid due to the `HOME` variable's value being output as `C:"`. I tried all of the below and nothing seemed to fix this:

```
> setx HOME C:\
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOME%
C:"

> setx HOME C:
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOME%
C:"

> setx HOME 'C:'
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOME%
C:"

> setx HOME "C:"
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOME%
C:"

> setx HOMEDRIVE C:
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOMEDRIVE%
C:

> setx HOME %HOMEDRIVE%
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOME%
C:"

> setx HOME HOMEDRIVE
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOME%
C:"    

> echo %HOMEDRIVE%
C:

> setx HOME %SYSTEMDRIVE%
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %HOME%
C:"
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm sure it's something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The foot-note in [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/505922/167784) mentions that the updated values of variables set using `setx` are not available until AFTER the script/terminal session as ended. I knew that `set` wasn't permanent and `setx` was, but I didn't realize that `setx` updates would not be available until I close and open a new command prompt.